# XSLT - find and replace wordt in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have this tool in a website system what has an XML feed as output, it gives the possibility to write functions yourself, it works like this:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="url:Encode(Regions/Region[1]/@Value)"/>



<msxml:script implements-prefix="url" language="C#">
    <msxml:assembly name="System.Web"/>
    <msxml:using namespace="System.Web"/>
    <![CDATA[
        public string Encode(string text)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
        }      
    ]]>
  </msxml:script>
```

So now I am looking for a find and replace function, a function that can filter a text and replace words in it, but I don't know where to start with this code.

Comment: You have posted some C# code (that is being called from XSLT, but that doesn't matter for the task of replacing words in a text), do you really not know how to use use the .NET framework's String and regular expression classes to replace words in a text? If the problem is specific to XML, then you need to show us a sample of the XML, unless you have your text in different elements or in child elements where you want to preserve them there is no difference in the function call shown in your sample to any other function call to C#.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents on the C# task.

Answer (score 1):

Since XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0, you can use the XPath's standard function [fn:replace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) for string search/replace in your XSLT stylesheet. Any XSLT >= 2.0 processor (e.g. [SAXON](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/documentation.xml) ) should provide that out-of-the-box.